# Access Recent Contacts in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, contacts

Can you programmatically access recent contacts in iOS 8? When you double-tap the home button, these contacts show at the top.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771266/iphone-access-voice-call-log

Comment: It's not call history though :/ 
It's whoever you last interacted with.